# SQL Execute on Certain Date Query

Tags: mysql

I have a small database with my website and I would like to execute a subtraction from everyone's account on a certain date like:

```
UPDATE Loan SET balance = (balance-amount)
"WHERE Day = 15"
```

Obviously the last part is just a guess but I have no due date in the loan table so sadly I can't do subtract when curDate= duedate sort of thing so I thought I would just do a set day when everyone's balance is subtracted on a set day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the [DAY()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) from `NOW()` function and can use it in your query like

```
UPDATE Loan SET balance = (balance-amount)
WHERE DAY(NOW()) =15
```

[See fiddle to get day from NOW()](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/31084)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Ah Brilliant, simple and clean. Is there a way to have this running in the background so I don't have to execute the query every day or is that something else completely?

Comment: @Softey not sure about the mysql event scheduler but if you are using any script then you can make a cron job and schedule it as you like to run the query

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Ok I have seen mysql event scheduler where I could do something like/
`CREATE EVENT loandeduction
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 4 WEEK
STARTS 23/02/2014
ENDS '23/02/2016 

DO
BEGIN
   UPDATE Loan SET balance = (balance-amount)
WHERE DAY(NOW()) =15
END//
DELIMITER ;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain some kind of reference date in order for this to work.

If everyone pays on the same day of the month, add a table that preserves the last time you extracted the fee.  You'll calculate the next fee date using the period and the last time you extracted it.

Remind me not to go to your website.  Too many fees.

Comment: Ha, I don't think anyone would want to go to my website hehe.